# Getting an Account List from Mainnet?

Tags: cleos

Is there a way to get a list of all account holders addresses with their EOS balance on mainnet without downloading the whole blockchain for the purpose of airdrop?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, there is no api available for that.

Comment: Thanks. I can only think of a few ways of doing this.   
1. Download the whole blockchain and extract the address from there.   
2. Using the etherscan.io to get all addresses.

Was wondering what's the best way to do an airdrop?

Comment: I'm also looking for this, like reading the table where the contract stores the accounts, something like `cleos get table eosio.token eosio accounts` but didn't returned what I thought it should.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no api for listing accounts on the MainNet.

Comment: Any other ways of getting the accounts? Thanks for the help.